# Button can't be clicked in iOS and MacCatalyst where is near the bottom in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have a `ContentPage` in my `MAUI` application. This page has a list of labels and entries and at the end 2 buttons:

```
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding WordTypes}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding WordTypeText}" />

        <Label Text="label_x" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding entry_x}" />

        <StackLayout IsVisible="false">
            <StackLayout.Triggers>
                <!-- Spanish -->
                <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding WordTypeText}" 
                                          Value="Verb" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </StackLayout.Triggers>
    
            <!-- More labels and entries -->
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- More labels and entries -->

        <Button Text="Cancel"
                Clicked="buttonCancel_Clicked" />
        <Button Text="Save"
                Clicked="buttonSave_Clicked" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`WordTypes` has 2 values: *Verb* and *Noun*. When the `WordTypeText` has value *Verb* I want to display more labels and entries.

The application is working in every platform.

There is a funny behaviour only in iOS and MacCatalyst. If I have to scroll the `ContentPage` to click the *Save* button, the application doesn't fire the function `buttonSave_Clicked`. If in MacCatalyst I resize the window, the button can be clicked and works as I expected.

Visual example. In MacCatalyst I have this window and if I click on the *Save* button, it is not working.

[image]

If I resize the window (only few pixels) it is working.

[image]

Has anybody else faced this issue? How can I fix it for iOS and MacCatalyst?

### Update

I read the suggested post on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14257) and I tried to follow what they said was working.

I tried to add in the constructor of the page this code

```
MyVerticalStackLayout.SizeChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    (MyScrollView as IView).InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

but it is now working. Another workaround is to add a box at the bottom of the page like

```
<BoxView BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="200" />
```

and the result is...

[image]

the `Transparent` `BackgroundColor` is working as you can see and I can't still click the button.

I read in NET8 this issue is fixed but there is no way to use NET8 with Visual Studio for Mac and for Windows I have to install the prerelease of Visual Studio.

Comment: It's likely a MAUI bug but can you try temporarily change your `ScrollView` into a `VerticalStackLayout` and see if it's fixed?

Comment: but the `VerticalStackLayout` doesn't scroll

Comment: Yeah it's just to confirm it's a problem with `ScrollView`. This may not be perfect but what if you put some padding at the bottom for either the `VerticalStackLayout` or `ScrollView`?

Comment: Known issue. Fixed in a Preview build, but not yet backported to .Net 7. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

- Fixed in .Net 8 Preview: [iOS ScrollView ContentSize (content beyond screen)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/14176).
- That also fixes [Button at the bottom not clickable](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14257).

Until this is backported to .Net 7:

- As a temporary workaround, move the buttons OUTSIDE the ScrollView.
- In other situations, calling `myScrollView.InvalidateMeasure();` (or maybe `myPage.InvalidateMeasure();` - not clear from the comment in 2nd linked issue.) sometimes fixes. E.g. in the event that triggers when scrollview scrolls, call that.

Comment: Shall I move to NET8 already? I'm doing this MAUI project to learn and time I finish the project NET8 will be release (November 2023).

Comment: Sure. Worth a try. Should be stable enough to develop with.

Comment: Unfortunately, NET8 is not supported on Visual Studio for Mac https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15965

Comment: In VS Mac / Settings, select Preview Features. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/16017

Comment: .NET8 is supported on Visual Studio for Mac. You may refer to [How to update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#how-to-update). @Enrico

Comment: I'm using .net 8 (PC) and this is still an issue for me.  The work around doesn't seem to work either.